# sqlite INSERT OR IGNORE doesn't work

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I've been trying for a while but can't find a mistake

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS participants(
   FirstName TEXT, 
   LastName TEXT, 
   ChatID INTEGER, UNIQUE(ChatID) )"
```

And here's how I try to insert data:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO participants (
FirstName, LastName, ChatID) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 
(FirstName ,LastName , ChatID))
```

I've tried creating using PRIMARY KEY instead of UNIQUE but that didn't work too.
I'm using SQLite with Python if that matters.

```
def create_first_table():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS participants(FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, ChatID INTEGER, UNIQUE(ChatID) )")
    cursor.close()

def dynamic_data_entry(fname, lname, chatid):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    FirstName = fname
    LastName = lname
    ChatID = chatid
    cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO participants (FirstName , LastName , ChatID ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (FirstName ,LastName , ChatID ))
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: You haven't said what is going wrong.

Comment: @DanielRoseman my bad, I get duplicates in my table

Comment: Since you're only creating the table if it doesn't already exist, are you sure there is a unique constraint on `ChatID`?  Have you checked the actual schema?

Comment: To edit your question, click "edit". And some example data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using AUTOINCREMENT in conjunction with PRIMARY KEY. Also, don't send a value for the Id in your SQL query.

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO participants ( FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?)", (FirstName ,LastName))
```